# Single Word Request for Orders "Sent Off" to Another Company for Processing

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to use in an order management application to name orders which have been "sent off" to a second company and are awaiting shipment. We use "PROCESSED" on our end for this. I suppose something like "DELEGATED" would work, but it seems slightly off in this context. I would like to stay away from phrases like "AWAITING SHIPMENT" because it is ambiguous (which company is in control of the order?). Hopefully there is a word I have simply forgotten or do not know that conveys this adequately.

Comment: Can you explain your work flow slightly? I'm confused how something can be "sent off"  but is still "awaiting shipment"... Anyway, have you considered something like "in transit" or does that fall into the "ambiguous" category?

Comment: What Catija said about work flow. Can you use "dispatched"?

Comment: An order management application should have a "Responsible Party" field to clear up any ambiguity.  Also, it would be helpful to know if the second party in your explanation is a vendor or a fulfillment center.

Comment: It's a fulfillment center that has a different manufacturing process than we do. The status will mean we've transmitted the order to them but it is awaiting shipment from there, as opposed to awaiting shipment from here. You can filter orders by these status indicators so it already has to be on a separate status to be coming from the other company, thus "Responsible Party" is redundant here.

Comment: I spent an inordinate number of seconds thinking someone wanted to send a single word request to another company for processing. I'm like, that's got to violate the ToS.

Comment: *Subcontracted*? *Outsourced*?

Comment: Would it help to differentiate between the two types of shipment? As I understand it, your oma records 'inbound' shipments, that is from you as a manufacturer to the fulfillment centre, and subsequent 'outbound' shipments, from the centre to vendors etc.

Comment: Perhaps these orders have been “forwarded”?

Comment: For lack of a better word, I ended up using 'forwarded', Jim. If you'd like to put it as an answer I can and will accept it.

Comment: If "*awaiting reception*" corresponds to this process step, it doesn't seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

"Outsourced" is a good word to denote that the work / items are being handed over to an outside contractor.
If you want to emphasize that the orders are awaiting shipment, you could use "pending" or "outgoing".

Answer (score 0):

I thought of outsourced,but the only problem is that it cannot be outsourced and awaiting shipment.  I think I understand what you're trying to say i.e. that you outsource one of the stages in the manufacturing process, but that you don't necessarily want to say that and are therefore looking for a word that would "disguise" this in a way. If this is so, it is probably preferable to be upfront about it.

Answer (score -1):

Transiting is the word I recomend.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). This is a good word and it may fit the OP's needs, but to make it a [good answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) I suggest expanding it with a dictionary definition and/or examples of usage, with references